# Random number generation with Poisson distribution in Matlab

Tags: matlab, poisson

I am trying to simulate an arrival process of vehicles to an intersection in Matlab. The vehicles are randomly generated with Poisson distribution.

Let´s say that in one diraction there is the intensity of the traffic flow 600 vehicles per hour. From what I understood from theory, the lambda of the Poisson distribution should be 600/3600 (3600 sec in 1 hour).

Then I run this cycle:

```
for i = 1:3600
    vehicle(i) = poissrnd(600/3600);
end
```

There is one problem: when I count the "ones" in the array `vehicle` there are never 600 ones, it is always some number around, like 567, 595 and so on.

The question is, am I doing it wrong, i.e. should lambda be different? Or is it normal, that the numbers will never be equal?

Comment: In case you have difficulty understanding the basic problem here, consider this: Suppose you flip 4 coins, will you always have 2 heads up? How can you always get 2 with heads up?!

Answer (score 3):

If you generate a random number, you can have an expectation of the output.

If you actually knew the output it would not be random anymore.

As such you are not doing anything wrong.

You could make your code a bit more elegant though.

Consider this vectorized approach:

```
vehicle = poissrnd(600/3600,3600,1)
```

---

If you always want the numbers to be the same (for example to reproduce results) try setting the state of your random generator.

If you have a modern version (without old code) you could do it like so:

```
rng(983722)
```

---

Comment: There is not problem with the random distribution of ones and zeros in the array, meaning they change in the array everytime I run the cycle, but the problem for me is that the number of ones in the array I want to be exactly 600. Because if the intensity is 600 veh/h then there should be 600 ones after the cycle ends...

Comment: @Mara Always having exactly 600 ones in 3600 values, and having a poisson random distribution **CANNOT** happen at the same time. You can either generate 3600 seconds with the distribution, or keep adding seconds untill you have 600 observations, this will not happen at the same time. If you don't care about the distribution but always want 600 out of 3600 values, try this: `randperm(3600,600)`

Comment: I see now, that was the problem, I thought I can have poisson distribution of 3600 values with exact number of ones. I just hoped that I can spread out exactly 600 ones in 3600 values randomly according to the poisson distribution, nevermind, thanks for answers